# Unable to run jmeter script with HTTP Cookie Manager with maven

Tags: maven-2, jmeter

Recently I'm working with test automation. The goal is to get quicker feedback so we decided to use maven-jmeter-plugin, jmeter scripts and Hudson.

I have wrote some example jmeter scripts templates and they are working fine (just a quick smoke test for accessing pages).

The problem is that script I have to complete requires 'HTTP Cookie Menager' to run correctly.

Here is dummy script I'm using at the moment trying identify what is wrong.

```
Test Plan
 |-> Thread Group
      |-> HTTP Cookie Menager
      |-> Loop Controler
          |-> HTTP request
```

I use the same configuration as in other working examples I have prepared (jmeter.properties, update.properties, system.properties - in the last file I keep values used by script like number of users, loop count, host, etc).

When I run it with mvn clean verify it returns following output:

```
mvn -e clean verify
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
        Profile with id: 'development,hudson' has not been activated.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.cybercom.test::peformance-test-mvn
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, verify]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory C:\Hudson\data\jobs\peformance-test-mvn\workspace\trunk\target
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] [jmeter:jmeter {execution: jmeter-tests}]
[INFO] Executing test: C:\Hudson\data\jobs\peformance-test-mvn\workspace\trunk\src\test\jmeter\temp.jmx
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There were test errors
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: There were test errors
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:55
6)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.jav
a:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There were test errors
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeterMojo.checkForErrors(JMeterMojo.java:115)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeterMojo.execute(JMeterMojo.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
```

The same script without HTTP Cookie Menager works perfectly well, but as I mentioned this is just dummy script to investigate what is wrong.

I assume that pom file might be useful as well here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>peformance-test-mvn</artifactId>
    <name>${groupId}::${artifactId}</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jmeter-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <reportDir>target/jmeter-reports</reportDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <url>XXXX</url>
            <name>YYYY</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

What am I missing??

Thanks in advance
Pawel

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

commons-logging dependency was missing in maven-jmeter-plugin-1.0.pom

Adding following lines

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Solved problem.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version (1.4.1 when this was posted).  The plugin is no also available in mvn central repo, although the group id and artifact id had to change to enable it to be added to central.  More info available at http://jmeter.lazerycode.com